# Horizontal swipe grid menue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

[image]
Please can anyone help with acheiving such a menu w horizontal swipe with the marked pen options ?

Thanks alot
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think that is viewpager.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just need to know the control used to start with because iam asked to do exactly the same and i dont know where to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Here's [Android's guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Comment: Thanks alot, thats what im looking for